# Getting key error and Import error in Python code for YouTube data API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api, spyder

I am trying to run Python code to download YouTube data using the generated API key for YouTube. My problem is whenever I try to run the code I am getting warnings and error. The code worked once when I downloaded it from Coursera, but now after getting me the results once it has stopped working.

The output of this code is a CSV file containing video data like like count, view count, comment count dislike count, favorite count, etc. which I would use later to do some statistical analysis on R or Python as part of my course on Coursera.

PFB the code which I used: xxxxx is the API key for me which I generated from Google YouTube data API v3

```
Enter code here

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from apiclient.discovery import build
#from apiclient.errors import HttpError
#from oauth2client.tools import argparser # removed by Dongho
import argparse
import csv
import unidecode

# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & authentication ? Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(options):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    # Query term.
    search_response = youtube.search().list(q=options.q, part="id,snippet", maxResults=options.max_results).execute()

    videos = []
    channels = []
    playlists = []

    # Create a CSV output for video list
    csvFile = open('video_result.csv','w')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    csvWriter.writerow(["title","videoId","viewCount","likeCount","dislikeCount","commentCount","favoriteCount"])

    # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
    # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            #videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
            title = search_result["snippet"]["title"]
            title = unidecode.unidecode(title)  # Dongho 08/10/16
            videoId = search_result["id"]["videoId"]
            video_response = youtube.videos().list(id=videoId,part="statistics").execute()
            for video_result in video_response.get("items",[]):
                viewCount = video_result["statistics"]["viewCount"]
                if 'likeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    likeCount = 0
                else:
                    likeCount = video_result["statistics"]["likeCount"]
                if 'dislikeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    dislikeCount = 0
                else:
                    dislikeCount = video_result["statistics"]["dislikeCount"]
                if 'commentCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    commentCount = 0
                else:
                    commentCount = video_result["statistics"]["commentCount"]
                if 'favoriteCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    favoriteCount = 0
                else:
                    favoriteCount = video_result["statistics"]["favoriteCount"]

            csvWriter.writerow([title,videoId,viewCount,likeCount,dislikeCount,commentCount,favoriteCount])

    csvFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Search on YouTube')
    parser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default="Google")
    parser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    #try:
    youtube_search(args)
    #except HttpError, e:
    #    print ("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

Whenever I run the code I get following errors:

1. viewCount = video_result[u'statistics']["viewCount"]

   KeyError: 'statistics'
2. WARNING:googleapiclient.discovery_cache:file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Anaconda3\Anaconda3 4.2.0\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery_cache__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect
       from google.appengine.api import memcache
   ImportError: No module named 'google'

   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Anaconda3\Anaconda3 4.2.0\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery_cache\file_cache.py", line 33, in 
       from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
   ImportError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file

How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether you are having statistics as a key in *video_result*. The KeyError occurs when you try to access a Key in a Python Dict, which is not present. So, the better way would be to use 'get()' while looking for a key,
Eg:  video_result.get('statistics') 
This will handle you Key Error. 
The second error is coming due to the missing import statements. The file is not able to import the imported file/function, and that's why it is throwing an exception while reporting an exception.

Comment: I tried video_result..get('Statistics') but it's not getting me the required result. The code ran for 1-2 times earlier without any changes when I downloaded it and gave me 25 video results ( as you can see at the bottom the max limit of results that can be extracted I have set them to 25) but due to some reason, it stopped working now.